# Filezilla: GnuTLS error when using FTPES

Tags: ftp

```
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 60 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 AUTH TLS OK.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Error:  GnuTLS error -50: The request is invalid.
Error:  Failed to initialize TLS.
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I'm trying to connect to a site using FTPES. It worked before on Fedora/Filezilla. But now I'm using Scientific-Linux with Filezilla, and it gives this. What am I missing?

Comment: so your saying that this is not a filezilla-related bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With FileZilla 3.5.2 it works perfectly. With FileZilla 3.5.3 it produces the error message above. So it's a bug AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

The error caused by the GnuTLS Handshake Failure between the client and server.  So, There is no issues with the ftp client - filezilla or TLS.Issues might be lies on firewall setting of your linux box

Comment: I disable iptables and load ftp_conntrack, but it's still the same!